# Internet requirement while upgrading

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, update-manager, do-release-upgrade, 20.04

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. I am going to do that by using `sudo update-manager -d`. When I download whole update, does my internet connection has to be uninterrupted? I have mobile data and it might exceed during this process. So should I proceed or wait for stable internet connection?

Comment: Upgrade path from 18.04 ro 20.04 is not officially opened and is NOT recommended. Using `-d` you are forcing the upgrade. Most likely it will cause serious problems and can be done only by experienced users. If you odn't heve a reliable network connection, it is really a very bad idea to upgrade.

Comment: 99% that your effort will finish with a new install.

Comment: What will be the size of the update(which I have to download) in this case? And when will that path(18.04 to 20.4) open?

Comment: The path will open in the end of July. The size depends on what is installed.